# tkinter - how to stop and continue a game in tkinter keeping the last state

Tags: python, tkinter

code does the following:

1. "Start" button - changes its own position at random places of the screen every 500 milliseconds
2. "Stop" button -'freezes' the  "Start" button at its last position (or in other words, terminates the moveRand() command)

I tried to use btn1.config() to set the last position of the button, but it didn't work

````
from tkinter import *
import random

width = 600
height = 600

def moveRand():
    rx = random.randint(0, width - 50)
    ry = random.randint(0, height - 40)
    btn1.place(x=rx, y=ry)
    root.after(500, moveRand)

def stop():
    # stops the Start button
    


root = Tk()

root.geometry(f"{width}x{height}")
root.resizable(False, False)

button_frame = Frame(root)
button_frame.pack(expand=True, fill='both')


btn1 = Button(button_frame, text="Start", width=6, height=2,
            bg="green", fg="white", activeforeground="white",
            activebackground="green", command=moveRand)
btn1.place(x=50, y=50)

btn2 = Button(button_frame, text="Stop", width=6, height=2, command=stop)
btn2.place(x=120, y=50)

root.mainloop()```
````

Answer (score 2):

Use a Global variable to store the state of the game, if it is stopped or if it is running. With that you don't need to store the current position of the button, because it will already be rendered in the position of the last state.

If later you need to do something else and needs to come back the start button for the last position it was when the game stopped, then use the same approach and store the variables rx and ry in global variables as well.

```
from tkinter import *
import random

width = 600
height = 600

global stop_game


def moveRand():
    global stop_game
    rx = random.randint(0, width - 50)
    ry = random.randint(0, height - 40)
    btn1.place(x=rx, y=ry)
    if not stop_game:
        root.after(500, moveRand)


def start():
    global stop_game
    stop_game = False
    moveRand()


def stop():
    global stop_game
    stop_game = True


# stops the Start button


root = Tk()
stop_game = False

root.geometry(f"{width}x{height}")
root.resizable(False, False)

button_frame = Frame(root)
button_frame.pack(expand=True, fill='both')

btn1 = Button(button_frame, text="Start", width=6, height=2,
              bg="green", fg="white", activeforeground="white",
              activebackground="green", command=start)
btn1.place(x=50, y=50)

btn2 = Button(button_frame, text="Stop", width=6, height=2, command=stop)
btn2.place(x=120, y=50)

root.mainloop()
```